# Postgres: cannot have more than 2^32-2 commands in a transaction

Tags: postgresql

I am inserting a large file in chunks 70M rows with COPY command. The inserted rows are then processed with a trigger. I though that if I will not try to insert the whole file at once, I will not get the error:

`cannot have more than 2^32-2 commands in a transaction`

Unfortunately, I have the same error. The first file is inserted, for the second file it gives this error. Could anyone explain me, what is this error and how could I fix it?
The tables were UNLOGGED at the beggining and I wanted to make them LOGGED after the whole upload is finished and now I am trying to do LOGGING/UNLOGGING each step, however, I am not sure that this will help.

Comment: Your problem is the trigger. [LINK](http://www.postgresql-archive.org/transaction-limits-td1851267.html) `Offhand I think the only limit that might concern you is the CID limit 
of 2^32 SQL commands per transaction.  This does not directly stop a 
single command from processing any number of rows --- but, for example, 
if you have a per-row trigger that contains 10 SQL commands, you could 
only fire it about 400 million times within one transaction. `

Comment: I read this, but I do not really understand. The files contain the same number of rows and execute approximately the same number of statements (INSERT, SELECT). If I finish a with one file using COPY (finished successfully) and then I start a new file using COPY (the 2nd failed), is this considered as a new transaction? How could I debug this and what is the solution to the problem.
Should I perhaps COMMIT after the first file is finished?

Comment: You have to be specific what step are you doing. two separated COPY shouldnt be problem. What is the trigger? What happen if you disable the trigger?

Comment: Maybe both are `COPY` statements are running in the same transaction...

Comment: How can I finish a transaction and start a new one?
I COPY into a temptable. The trigger fires for each new insert then the trigger calls a function which is normalizing the data with checking whether the different string fields are already in the normalized tables. If yes, then it gets their ID and copies to a mapping table, if not then inserts then and then gets the new ID and inserts the collected IDs to a mapped table. The function does not write anything in the temptable. I am uploading at once three documents with three different table-sets, different named triggers and functions.

Comment: To end a transaction simply issue "commit"